# RDF/XML Representing address with blank nodes

Tags: blank-nodes, rdf-xml

I am new to RDF/XML notation and I am having trouble with addresses. I tried to google for examples but I can't find any; all I find are graphical notations, which isn't in the format I need.
[This is an example of what I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7XO5.png)

This is what I currently have:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:net="http://purl.org/net/VideoGameOntology" xmlns:sc="http://www.schema.org/">
   <sc:Property sc:about="https://schema.org/VideoGame">
      <sc:publisher>
         <sc:Property sc:about="https://schema.org/person">
            <sc:name xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[Kinetic Games]]></sc:name>
            <sc:address>
               <sc:streetAddress sc:about="https://schema.org/address"><![CDATA[Stag Gates House, 63/64 The Avenue]]></sc:streetAddress>
               <sc:addressLocality sc:about="https://schema.org/address"><![CDATA[Southampton]]></sc:addressLocality>
               <sc:addressRegion sc:about="https://schema.org/address"><![CDATA[Hampshire]]></sc:addressRegion>
               <sc:addressCountry sc:about="https://schema.org/address"><![CDATA[United Kingdom]]></sc:addressCountry>
               <sc:postalCode sc:about="https://schema.org/address"><![CDATA[SO17 1XS]]></sc:postalCode>
            </sc:address>
         </sc:Property>
      </sc:publisher>
   </sc:Property>
</rdf:RDF>
```

This is the kind of error I got:
Error: {E202} Expecting XML start or end element(s). String data "Stag Gates House, 63/64 The Avenue" not allowed. Maybe there should be an rdf:parseType='Literal' for embedding mixed XML content in RDF. Maybe a striping error.[Line = 11, Column = 102]
Error: {E201} Multiple children of property element[Line = 12, Column = 59]

Answer (score 1):

[I finally managed to find this reference for blank nodes RDF/XML rotation](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/#figure13), and this is the final validated code. [image: this is the final validated code.] Hope this helps someone else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:net="http://purl.org/net/VideoGameOntology" xmlns:sc="http://www.schema.org/" xmlns:vgo="http://purl.org/net/videogameontology#">
   <sc:Property sc:about="https://schema.org/VideoGame">
      <sc:publisher sc:resource="https://kineticgames.co.uk/" sc:nodeID="KIGames" />
   </sc:Property>
   <sc:Property sc:nodeID="KIGames">
      <sc:name xml:lang="en"><![CDATA[Kinetic Games]]></sc:name>
      <!--Blank Node Kinetic Games address-->
      <sc:address sc:nodeID="KIGamesAdd" />
   </sc:Property>
   <!--Blank Node Kinetic Games address-->
   <sc:Property sc:nodeID="KIGamesAdd">
      <sc:streetAddress><![CDATA[Stag Gates House, 63/64 The Avenue]]></sc:streetAddress>
      <sc:addressLocality><![CDATA[Southampton]]></sc:addressLocality>
      <sc:addressRegion><![CDATA[Hampshire]]></sc:addressRegion>
      <sc:addressCountry><![CDATA[United Kingdom]]></sc:addressCountry>
      <sc:postalCode><![CDATA[SO17 1XS]]></sc:postalCode>
   </sc:Property>
</rdf:RDF>
```